# Tabs, newlines, DocumentFilters and eclipse text

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, documentfilter

So, I have an additional issue regarding [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179274/filtering-out-tab-character-with-documentfilter) question.

Once I apply the fix, go to notepad, typeout bunch of tabs and newlines with some random characters and then paste them into my program, it all works peachy.

However, being the closest text with bunch of tabs and newlines, I tried pasting a part the code itself to the JTextArea. All tabs and newlines stuck there and weren't filtered out.

Although my users probably won't paste eclipse code into my program , I can't be sure that eclipse code is the only exception. So I'd like to know why is this happening.

Also, I'd like for my code to filter out the blank characters except for space caracter and turn them into space character. I think tab and newline are the only ones, but if there are any more, please let me know.

Anyway, what do I have to change to make it work?

Here's the fixed SSCCE:

```
package core;

import java.awt.BorderLayout; import java.awt.Dimension; import java.io.FileNotFoundException; import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFrame; import javax.swing.JTextArea; import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument; import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet; import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException; import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;

class DefaultDocFilter extends DocumentFilter {
    public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offs,String str, AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException 
    {
        if ((fb.getDocument().getLength() + str.length()) <= 2000)
        {
            str = str.replaceAll("\n", " ");
            str = str.replaceAll("\t", " ");
            fb.insertString(offs, str, a);
        }
        else
        {
            int spaceLeft = 2000 - fb.getDocument().getLength();
            if (spaceLeft <= 0)
                return;

            str = str.substring(0, spaceLeft);
            str = str.replaceAll("\n", " ");
            str = str.replaceAll("\t", " ");

            fb.insertString(offs, str, a);
        }
    }

    public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offs, int length, String str, AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException 
    {
        if (str.equals("\n") || str.equals("\t"))
        { 
            str = "";
        }
        if ((fb.getDocument().getLength() + str.length() - length) <= 2000)
        {
            str = str.replaceAll("\n", " ");
            str = str.replaceAll("\t", " ");
            fb.replace(offs, length, str, a);
        }
        else
        {
            int spaceLeft = 2000 - fb.getDocument().getLength() + length;
            if (spaceLeft <= 0)
                return;

            fb.replace(offs, length, str.substring(0,spaceLeft).replaceAll("\n", " "), a);
        }
    } }


public class Main {
    public static JFrame mWindow;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {   
        //create main window
        mWindow = new JFrame("title");
        mWindow.setSize(1000, 800);
        mWindow.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1000, 800));
        mWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mWindow.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JTextArea a = new JTextArea();
        AbstractDocument doc = (AbstractDocument) a.getDocument();
        doc.setDocumentFilter(new DefaultDocFilter());
        a.setLineWrap(true);
        a.setWrapStyleWord(true);

        mWindow.add(a);
        mWindow.pack();

        mWindow.setVisible(true);

        mWindow.repaint();
        mWindow.validate();
    } }
```

It's Java 1.7. Create a new project, package core, file Main.

Document filter is the first class and it's applied to the JTextArea you'll see. Everything you need is within that class.

EDIT: I fixed the SSCCE. Also, the problem only occurs when you try to paste more character that can fit the JTextArea (I set limit to 2000). Then tas and newlines wont get filtered out.

Comment: Wow, I missed your 100s of lines short code snippets. :)

Comment: We'll it's better that what I usually give, anyway... :D
You'll just have to copy a bit more text and it will compile a tad longer, but everything you need to look at is in the top of the file within a short class.

Comment: Better you post short code that shows the problem when we run it.

Comment: It does... You just have to press file->new->ok.
Then JTextAreas appear and you paste all you want in them.

Comment: Dumping your whole code in a question does not encourage others to answer your question. Trim down whatever is not necessary to reproduce your problem. Checkout [what an SSCCE is](http://sscce.org)

Comment: I fixed it. Random text to break char limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `replace` method, in the `else` part of the method, you only replace "\n" but not "\t"

Comment: Nope, that's correct.

Try changing that and pasting more characters than JTextArea can take.

Comment: @Karlovsky120 Sorry misread your question. Thought you were trying to limit the number of chars to 2000. The problem comes from your `else` which does not remove tabs.

Comment: Yeah, that was it. I've been looking this code for half an hour and I kept missing it...